# T-SQL transactions and table locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

If I want to select all records in a table that have not been processed yet and then update those records to reflect that they have been processed, I would do the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [flag] IS NULL;
 UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [flag] = 1 WHERE [flag] IS NULL;
```

How do I ensure that the UPDATE works on only the records I just selected, ie, prevent the UPDATE of any records that may have been added with [flag] = NULL that occurred AFTER my SELECT but before my UPDATE by another process?  Can I wrap those two statements in a transaction?  Do I have to put a lock on the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single call, no transaction needed by using the OUTPUT clause.

XLOCK exclusively locks the rows to stop concurrent reads (eg another process looking for NULL rows)

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable WITH (XLOCK)
SET flag = 1 
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE flag IS NULL;
```

Comment: What's the earliest version of SQL Server that supports the `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: ..and given OP uses SSIS too, based on other questions.

Comment: yes, i was interested in 2k5, sorry, i should've mentioned that. this looks like the winner for my purposes -- thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the OUTPUT clause to return a result set from the UPDATE itself:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] 
SET [flag] = 1 
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE [flag] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable] (UPDLOCK)
 WHERE [flag] IS NULL;

UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] 
   SET [flag] = 1 
 WHERE [flag] IS NULL;
```

For more info on locking hints:

- [The SELECT/UPDATE problem, or, why UPDLOCK?](http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com/2004/03/selectupdate-problem-or-why-updlock.html)
- [Locking Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1.  Note that this would need to be in a transaction for the update lock to carry through to the update statement.

Comment: Still 2 statements though that aren't needed with SQL Server 2005 +

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap these two statements in a transaction with read_committed or more restricted scope. Its a bit expensive and might cause other issues. King's solution is more workable.